# How to hide/disable UISearchBars Scopebar

Tags: ios, ios4, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I am using a sample code from apple developer site as a base : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 
Its a simple table Search code. What I am trying to do is populate a table with my own data with different cell styles and searching the contents using the search bar. Now I was successfully able to complete all what I wanted to accomplish here but I want to hide the scopebar which appears when user clicks on search bar. I tried setting scopeButtonTitles = nil using method found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

But still the scope bar shows up. If you run the table search bar you can see the scopebar with titles as 'All,device,desktop,portable', I tried searching for an array containig these values but never found one. So can anyone please tell me how to hide the scope bar. What methods should I implement and where should I implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`showsScopeBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW22) property. Set it to `NO`.

**EDIT**

For `UISearchBar`s handled by `UISearchDisplayController`, you will have to the make that array `nil`.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil;
```

Comment: I tried this and set  self.showsScopeBar = NO; in viewdidLoad but still I am getting the scope bar! Am I setting it in wrong place?

Comment: Edited with relevance to the sample project above. The last statement should do the job for you.

Comment: It worked! but then I lost the search functionality? What is exactly happening? I tried removing 'self.showScopeBar = NO' still there is no search functionality. But the scope bar is now hidden.

Comment: Update: there was a code using the contents of scope for searching the table contents. I modified the function accordingly and it worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Was really struggeling with this, trying to set showsScopeBar = NO. This did the trick!